# show posts only clicked category from sidebar menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have different category posts. Categories are showing in sidebar. I want that when i clicked on any category then only this category posts should display in main container and by default only first category posts should display.

Comment: post code which you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require programing, you have to associate the category to the post from the Admin Dashboard, while editing the post. The categories to be linked are in a meta box on the right.

Comment: i have already linked but when i am clicking category in sidebar menu it is going page not found page

Comment: All posts are showing in container and category menus are showing in sidebar. when i amclicking on any category i want that only that category post should display and other hide.

Comment: I suggest you write another question explaining correctly which is the problem you are facing.